# How to execute conditional statement (which is in string format) in javascript which comes from database

Tags: javascript

```
var cal_Ref='IF (S23<1.5){ S23=1.5;}';
eval(cal_Ref);
```

Throwing error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Expected ';'

Comment: Javascript is `case-sensitive` scripting language..So, `IF` wont work. Try with `if`.

Comment: Would also note that S23 does not appear to be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var cal_Ref='IF (S23<1.5){ S23=1.5;}';
```

to

```
var cal_Ref='if (S23<1.5){ S23=1.5;}'; // small `if`
```

as *JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.*

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you are trying to store the output of condition **var cal_Ref=if** this will have an error.

And for something from db you can have use of documents as:
**var txtid = document.getElementById('txtid').value;**

Answer (score 0):

```
  var S23=1.1;var cal_Ref='if (S23<1.5){ S23=1.5;}';
    eval(cal_Ref);
```

Please change the code as above chanage'IF' to 'if' also you can use

Conditional operator '?' instead of 'if'

```
var S23=1.1;var cal_Ref=' (S23<1.5)?( S23=1.5):(S23=1.0)';
eval(cal_Ref);
```